# how to get nested data in Vue js

Tags: nested, vue.js

I have a view page showing a list of items. When an item is clicked, the current item details will show on the detailed view page. 
The heading and description for the current item are showing perfectly, however for each item I also have a nested gallery with 3 images and I need to display them too. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpg9dszq/25/)

I am using [List Rendering in Vue JS](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html)

**HTML**

```
  <h1 v-if="isActive(0)">Master View</h1>
  <h1 v-if="!isActive(0)">Detailed View</h1>

  <div id="breadcrumb">
    <a v-if="!isActive(0)" @click="setActive(0)">&lt; Back</a>
  </div>

  <main>
    <article>
      <h2>{{items[active].title}}</h2>
      <p>{{items[active].description}}</p>
    </article>

    <ul id="master-ul" v-if="isActive(0)">
      <li v-for="item in items" @click="setActive($index)">
        <img v-bind:src="item.thumbnail" alt="{{item.title}}" />
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul v-if="!isActive(0)">
      <!-- Need to display the nested images from the current index item -->
      <li v-for="item in items">
        <img v-bind:src="item.gallery.image" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: 0,
    items: [{
      title: 'Default',
      description: 'lorem ipsum default',
      thumbnail: 'http://placehold.it/250x250'

    }, {
      title: 'One',
      description: 'lorem ipsum 1',
      thumbnail: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+1+Thumb',
      gallery: {
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+1+image+1',
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+1+image+2',
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+1+image+3'
      }

    }, {
      title: 'Two',
      description: 'lorem ipsum 2',
      thumbnail: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+2+Thumb',
      gallery: {
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+2+image+1',
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+2+image+2',
        image: 'http://placehold.it/250x250?text=Item+2+image+3'
      }

    }]
  },
  methods: {
    isActive: function(i) {
      return this.active === i
    },
    setActive: function(i) {
      return this.active = i
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

use a conmputed property to get the gallery for active item

use another v-for directive on the `<img>` tag directly to loop through the images in the gallery.

```
computed: {
  activeImages: function () {
    return this.items[this.active].gallery
  }
}
<ul v-if="!isActive(0)">
 <li>
    <img  v-for="image in activeImages" v-bind:src="image" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah sorry my apologies. This didn't worked. Right now it's grabbing the last image from each item. https://jsfiddle.net/Lpg9dszq/6/. I need it to grab the images from the selected item.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, if your data really looks like your exampe, the `gallery` objects are not valid Javascript, as they have duplicate keys, keys have to be unique.

Comment: I am getting a console error in Vue Dev Tool saying '[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "item[active].gallery"'. And I think I have fixed the duplicate keys issue.. https://jsfiddle.net/Lpg9dszq/13/

Comment: I also tried doing item[0].gallery but I get the same error